# non-numeric argument to binary operator when using ComplexHeatmap

Tags: r

I get `non-numeric argument to binary operator` error when I run the last line of code.

I understand that the error message means that I'm trying to perform a binary operation with something that isn't a number. Hence, I added the following function:

```
'+' <- function(e1, e2) {
  if (is.character(e1) | is.character(e2)) {
    paste0(e1, e2)
  } else {
    base::`+`(e1, e2)
  }
}
```

However, I'm still getting an error

```
library(ComplexHeatmap)


    annCol  <- surv.info[,c("age", "malignancy_type", "pathologic_stage", "race", "gender"), drop = FALSE]

    age = circlize::colorRamp2(breaks = c(min(annCol$age), median(annCol$age), max(annCol$age)), colors = c("#003f5c", "#f1f1f1", "#FFA600"))
```

Traceback:

```
Error in x - break2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Data:

```
> dput(annCol[1:10,])
structure(list(age = c("53", "71", "80", "50", "66", "38", "69", 
"56", "66", "66"), malignancy_type = c("", "", "", "", "prior malignancy", 
"", "prior malignancy", "", "prior malignancy", ""), pathologic_stage = c("stage ii", 
"stage i", "stage ii", "stage i", "stage i", "stage iii", "stage i", 
"stage i", "stage i", "stage i"), race = c("white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "black or african american", 
"white", "white"), gender = c("male", "male", "male", "male", 
"male", "male", "female", "female", "male", "female")), row.names = c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A", 
"TCGA.4A.A93W.01A"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: your age values are `character`, make sure you convert them to `integer` first

Comment: I would strongly recommend **against** overloading the `+` operator.  Just write a line of code that checks the class of your inputs :   `foo <- if(is.character.....[stuff]) paste0(e1,e2) else e1+e2` .   **HOWEVER** there are *lots* of object classes which are not "character" but still cannot be added together because they aren't a subclass of "numeric."   Why in the world are you returning either a charstring or a numeric value in the first place?  This has really bad code smell.